# PyQt сортировка в TableWidget по столбцу с QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Подскажите если в TableWidget имеется столбец в который внедрены QComboBox

`myTable.setSortingEnabled(True)
 myTable.setCellWidget(0, 0, QComboBox())`

Сортировка по этому столбцу не работает. Как сделать так чтобы сортировка работала по значениям из QComboBox()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390129/qt-how-can-i-sort-qtablewidget-column-if-the-cells-are-widgets

Answer (score 1):

c `QTableWidget` сложновато, а с `QTableView` можно так (как вариант):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random


class ComboBoxDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    mySignal = pyqtSignal(int, str)      

    def __init__(self, parent, choices):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.items = choices

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QComboBox(parent)
        editor.addItems(self.items)
        return editor

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.DisplayRole)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        text = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole) or ""
        editor.setCurrentText(text)
        self.mySignal.emit(index.row(), editor.currentText())

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self._tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._tableView)

        self._model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 4)   
        self._tableView.setModel(self._model)
        self._tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 

        self._listCombo = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']
        delegate = ComboBoxDelegate(self._tableView, self._listCombo)
        self._tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, delegate)
        delegate.mySignal.connect(self.delegateMySignal)
        self._tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        now_second = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toSecsSinceEpoch()
        texts_column_2 = ['один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять',]       

        for i in range(self._model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self._model.columnCount()):
                if j == 1: 
                    t = QtCore.QDateTime.fromSecsSinceEpoch(random.randint(0, now_second))
                    text = t.toString("dd MMM yyyy")
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                    it.setData(t.toSecsSinceEpoch(), QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                elif j == 2:  
                    text = f"{texts_column_2[i]}"
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                    it.setData(i, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)   
                elif j == 3:                   # !!! для реализации сортировки по значениям из QComboBox 
                    self._text3 = 'm1'
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem(self._text3)
                    it.setData(self._text3, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)                    
                else:
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))

                self._model.setItem(i, j, it)

        self._model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        # отсортируем по столбцу с индексом 2, по возрастанию
        self._model.sort(2, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder) 

    # !!! для реализации сортировки по значениям из QComboBox 
    def delegateMySignal(self, i, test):  
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem(test)
        it.setData(test, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)           
        self._model.setItem(i, 3, it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(450, 250)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]